# How to collect from a stream which maps to multiple results?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to map each entry in my list by calling `expand()`, which returns multiple entries, and then collect the result as a list.

Without streams, I would accomplish this like:

```
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> expanded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : myList) {
        expanded.addAll(expand(s));
    }
    return expanded;

    private List<String> expand(String x) {
        return Arrays.asList(x, x, x);
    }
```

How can I accomplish this with streams? This gives a compilation error:

`return myList.stream().map(this::expand).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: `myList.stream() .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x, x, x)) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) should help you :

```
return myList.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> expand(x).stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
return myList.stream().map(this::expand).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

returns `List<List<String>>` because `myList.stream().map(this::expand)` returns a stream typed as `Stream<List<String>>` as you pass to `map()` a variable declared `List<String>` variable and not `String`.

You don't want that.

So chain `Stream.map()` with `Stream.flatMap()` to amalgamate `Stream<List<String>>` to `Stream<String>` :

```
return myList.stream()
             .map(this::expand)
             .flatMap(x->x.stream())
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

use `flatMap` to convert the `Stream<List<String>` to a `Stream<String>`:
`return myList.stream().map(this::expand).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`